# Flutter PageView children scrolled together when i am using PageView -> ListView | SingleChildScrollVIew

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-pageview

Flutter PageView children that is ListView scrolled when the one child scrolled. They are sharing one scrolling behavior.
How can I fix this issue? Help me?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding specific ScrollController to each PageView's Scrolling widget.

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

add these line inside ListView:

```
ListView(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
```